# Are questions about starting an investment club/company on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, allowed-topics

We got this question on OnStartups that is a marginal fit for our site. Would it be accepted here?

[how does one start an investing club (as a company)?](http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/27327/how-does-one-start-an-investing-club-as-a-company)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I've migrated it over http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/9556/how-does-one-start-an-investing-club-as-a-company.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Investment clubs are by definition personal finance. How to organize one is on-topic imo.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is borderline, but acceptable.  We do have questions about investment clubs.  What gives mu pause is that this question ask specifically about incorporating an entity for it.  That said, we have fielded questions on single-person entities, as they do generally have a bearing on personal finance.